# Cleaner shorter code for if else to change the content dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a dataLayer generated by a system and I would like to change a specific content of my page depending on a value in the dataLayer. I came up with this conditional if else statement which it works fine but is there a better (shorter and cleaner) way to change the content of an element based on these values with jQuery?

```
for (const [value, selector] of [
  [dataLayer.majorValue, "#major-value"],
]) {
  if (value == 'Art' ) {
    $(selector).html('Art description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
  } else if (value == 'Business') {
    $(selector).html('Business description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
  } else if (value == 'Education') {
    $(selector).html('Education description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
  } else if (value == 'Humanities') {
    $(selector).html('Humanities description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
  } else if (value == 'Health') {
    $(selector).html('Health description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
  } else if (value == 'Mathematics') {
    $(selector).html('Mathematics description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
  } else if (value == 'Languages') {
    $(selector).html('Languages description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
  } else if (value == 'Sciences') {
    $(selector).html('Sciences description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting them in an object with same keys as `value` is simplest

```
const getDescription = value => {
    const descriptions = {
      'Art': 'Art description... ',
      'Business': 'Business description...',
      'Education': 'Education description....',
      // ....
      'Sciences': 'Sciences description....'
    };    
    return descriptions[value] || 'Default not found description';
}
    
$(selector).html(getDescription(value))
```

Comment: I like it. what does the return line do? do I need it?

Comment: Returns the description from the function. The function can be put elsewhere out of the other logic flow if needed

Comment: I should've been clearer, I was confused by the OR || 'Default not found description'

Comment: In case it's possible for `value` not to match any of the keys in the object. If that's not probable you don't need the `|| 'Default...'`

Comment: This is great and cleaner than conditionals. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 0):

replace if cascade with

```
switch(value) {
  case 'Art':
    $(selector).html('Art description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
    break;
  case 'Business':
    $(selector).html('Business description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
    break;
  case 'Education':
    $(selector).html('Education description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
    break;
  case 'Humanities':
    $(selector).html('Humanities description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
    break;
  case 'Health':
    $(selector).html('Health description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
    break;
  case == 'Mathematics':
    $(selector).html('Mathematics description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
    break;
  case 'Languages':
    $(selector).html('Languages description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
    break;
  case 'Sciences':
    $(selector).html('Sciences description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.');
    break;
  
  default:
    // default if one exists or could just be last one (sciences)
}
```

or

```
switch(value) {
  case 'Art':
    blurb = 'Art description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.';
    break;
  case 'Business':
    blurb = 'Business description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.';
    break;
  case 'Education':
    blurb = 'Education description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.';
    break;
  case 'Humanities':
    blurb = 'Humanities description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.';
    break;
  case 'Health':
    blurb = 'Health description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.';
    break;
  case 'Mathematics':
    blurb = 'Mathematics description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.';
    break;
  case 'Languages':
    blurb = 'Languages description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.';
    break;
  default:
    blurb = 'Sciences description lorem ipsum blurb goes here.';
    break;
 
}
$(selector).html(blurb);
```

or use a dictionary to look up blurb based on key.

Is the blurb you are getting returned from your function call or will it need to be hard coded into the page?